# How Does Running Multiple Server Instances Work In Regards to the User IP Address

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

If I'm running multiple web server instances can a client application (like a user using a web browser) be using the different instances or would they be routed to the same instance every time? Let's say they duplicate a tab or open a new tab are those tabs still using the same instance too?

This would be in `Azure` with `IIS`/`ASP.NET`.

Comment: I think I might have found the answer. According to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/288981/load-balanced-iis-7-5-web-server-asp-net-session-state-problem) the browser will hit whatever server instance is available and so you cannot rely on a single user hitting a single web server instance. LMK if I'm wrong!

Comment: No you are not wrong. In fact, in a multi instance environment *always* assume that there is no guarantee that the same instance will be used for a given client session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using load balance in any environment, you almost always have the option to set session affinity. It means basically, a client who is directed to server 1 on his first request will always be routed to the same server. Azure does provide this flexibility too without question. Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-distribution-mode) with some details on how to do that configuration.

There are a couple of ways how you could configure session affinity. One prominent way is by source IP. So, using a different tab or a different browser instance will not make any difference. Requests from a client machine will always carry the same IP address and hence will go to the same server. 
Here is the Powershell sample to set source IP based affinity:

Set-AzureLoadBalancedEndpoint -ServiceName MyService -LBSetName LBSet1 -Protocol TCP -LocalPort 80 -ProbeProtocolTCP -ProbePort 8080 –LoadBalancerDistribution sourceIP

[Here](https://mtharativ.wordpress.com/2018/05/06/how-network-address-translation-nat-affects-request-distribution-of-a-load-balanced-application-across-servers/) is some detail on a more specific scenario that happens when users access a load balanced site from behind a company;s firewall.